# Protocol for downloading file

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am looking for a protocol which is non-blocking(does not wait for missing packets) like UDP but it tracks the missing packets so I can download the missing packets later/in parallel. The main objective is to increase the download speed by avoiding waiting time for packets and still getting the complete file. Kindly if there is something like this out there that can help increase download speed then name it. Thanks.

Comment: um ... TCP doesnt wait for packets, it REORDERS SEGMENTS. Its a common misconception and most likely the very reason for many multiplayer computer-games being really awful in regards of networking; UDP isnt suitable for most cases.

Comment: TCP is a reliable transport protocol.  Therefore, there can be circumstances when it is doing nothing except waiting for one missing packet (and sending ACKs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Short answer: You don't. UDP does not have anything equivalent to TCP's sequence number / acknowledgement number mechanism to let you
>   track packets and detect packet loss.
>
> If the higher-level protocol that's running on top of UDP (RTP, TFTP,
>   etc.) has some sort of identification number or sequence number or
>   block number that is unique per packet and that changes in a
>   predictable way, then you could display that number in a custom column
>   and manually look for missing numbers, but there is no way in the UDP
>   protocol itself to identify missing packets.

Click [here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/14406/how-do-i-track-packet-loss-when-i-have-the-udp-protocol) for the source.